# SQL Server 2012 table data export to excel file

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012-express

I would like to export data from a SQL Server stored procedure to an Excel file. How can I achieve that?

I test like that:

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\test.xlsx;;HDR=YES', 
   'SELECT EmpID FROM [Sheet1$]')
select * from tb1
```

but it returns an error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I think it's because Excel doesn't have columns right? But there's no way to pre-write columns before exporting to Excel, and SQL Server can't create Excel by itself ...

I also tried with `bcp`:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM mydb.tb1" queryout 'D:\test.xlsx' -t, -c -S . -d DESKTOP-D3PCUR7 -T
```

It returns error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.

How can I export table to Excel easily in SQL Server?

Comment: Try using double quotes around your file name in your bcp command:
`bcp "SELECT * FROM mydb.tb1" queryout "D:\test.xlsx" -t , -c -S . -d DESKTOP-D3PCUR7 -T`

Comment: @marc_s, I already tried like that but still getting the same error. I change query like `SELECT * FROM mydb.dbo.tb1` but It still shows the same error.

Comment: Also: `bcp` cannot create `.xlsx` files directly - "only" csv/tsv which you can then import into Excel